# When using SonarLint in VSCode, how do you generate a report of local project violations?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, sonarlint

I just installed the SonarLint extension for VSCode (Windows 10).  When using my Java/Maven project, how do I generate a report of all violations in my project?  When I expand the "Sonar Lint Iusse List" on the left, there are no issues reported (even though I know, using Eclipse, that there are many SonarLint issues), only this

[image]

but I'm unclear what "Show All Locations Code Action" means.

Answer (score 1):

> ### [Code Action](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_code-action)
>
> Warnings and Errors can provide Code Actions (also known as Quick Fixes) to help fix issues. These will be displayed in the editor in the left margin as a lightbulb. Clicking on the lightbulb will either display the Code Action options or perform the action.

On your code editing page, find where there are errors or warnings, and click the yellow light bulb to expand the **Code Action** menu.

[image]

Open this menu in a place where *SonarLint issue* exists, there should be `Show all locations` option, just click it.

Comment: So the only way to run a report is to first find a warning or error in the code?

Comment: You can turn on the yellow light bulb anywhere, but I'm afraid the `Show all Locations` option only exists in *SonarLint issue*. I'm not very clear about the working mechanism of **SonarLint**, I just answer the doubt in your question. `but I'm unclear what "Show All Locations Code Action" means.`